# What C compiler matches Borland Turbo Link 5.1?

Tags: c, linker, turbo-c, borland-c++

We have an environment built upon Borland Turbo Assembler 5.3 and Turbo Link 5.1. We have to maintain some hereditary code in it, so throwing them away is out of the question. Now I want to introduce some C into it.

Neither GCC, nor Microsoft C/C++ compiler provide object file in Borland format. That's understandable. But somehow even Borland C++ 5.5 and Turbo C 2.0 don't. I mean, linker does link these objects with no warnings or errors, but the executable linked just crashes. Tried this with mere hello world, still crashes or does nothing visible and exits.

Looks like there is severe difference between versions and there should be specific C compiler for Turbo Link 5.1. Is is so? If it is, what compiler should I take?

Or, which came to mind just now, maybe I should rather do some TASM translation with, for instance, BCC instead and then just TASM it?

Comment: If you have a compiler that writes TASM that your assembler supports, that would seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the copyright date in the output from TASM5.1 (spotted [here](http://www.et.byu.edu/~rhelps/eet340/html/usingtasm.htm) ), and the dates on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B), I'd try Borland C++ 3.1 or Turbo C++ 3.1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to run the .exe file with "windows 95" compatibility? However, [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) is under the BSD License and has a -t switch for Borland's Tasm compatibility mode, maybe you want to try that?

Answer (score 2):

I think Turbo Assembler 5.x and Turbo Link 5.x support only 16-bit apps.
The last Borland C++ compiler that supported 16-bit is Borland C++ 5.02.

The newer ones, like BCC5.5 support only 32-bit, that is probably why the linked app crashed.

Comment: Actually, Borland Link 5.1 can tell 32-bit objects from 16-bit. It doesn't even start linking 32-bit without `/3` option, instead it just quits gracefully with appropriate message. The problem is, it is not very verbose about incorrect linking when bitness matches.